# How to classify a data as not matching any label

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, supervised-learning

I'm creating a supervised convnet which recognizes a phrase in a regional language.

For example:

> I have a dataset which contains 100 sounds for labels A and another 100 sounds for labels B. Now normal operation of the network is to differentiate a sound between label A and label B.

But let's say that I give a new sound to the network to classify, which is actually neither A nor B. I want the neural net to tell me that it doesn't qualify any of the labels.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Let's phrase it another way, decomposing into two problems:

1. given a sound, we want to know if it's of class A
2. given a sound, we want to know if it's of class B

This way of putting it is valuable to some techniques, notably "one-class classification" and "PU learning" (learning from positive and unlabeled examples). These techniques are very relevant when you want to know "does my item follow a given distribution D?", which is exactly what you're looking for.

Still, if you have (or can collect) a lot of data that is neither A nor B, you may simply label it as a garbage class C and use a common classifier - however, it may actually be harmful, because you're likely assuming wrong things about class C [Li, Liu and Ng, "Negative Training Data can be Harmful to Text Classification", 2010]. It *could* work and is much simpler to develop, may be good enough depending on your case.

Comment: as you said that creating a third class might actually harm the network, I won't be using it. Morever I actually have 10 classes and I don't think that creating a 10 binary classifiers is a good solution. Isn't there a way I can set some threshold on the distribution?

Comment: @penduDev "I don't think that creating 10 binary classifiers is a good solution" I know the feeling behind this, but honestly I'd give it a try if training the model isn't that expensive, machine learning is all about "good enough".

Comment: I'll give it a try!